# Má tradução: Medalha Ressurgimento

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Tradução da medalha Ressurgimento está incorreta:

#### Ressurgimento

> Respondeu depois de mais de 30 dias com uma pontuação de 2 ou superior

Sua descrição original é:

#### Revival

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more

#### Sugestão:

> Respondeu depois de mais de 30 dias e foi a primeira resposta a ter uma pontuação de 2 ou superior

Comment: Corrigido com: "Respondeu depois de mais de 30 dias e foi a primeira resposta com mais de 2 pontos" pra ficar um pouquinho menor

Comment: @Gabe, mas "mais de 2 pontos" é diferente de "pontuação de 2 ou superior". Então devia ser "com pelo menos 1 ponto"...

Comment: @bfavaretto Não sei se gosto de você me dando mais motivo pra ir lá acertar traduções....... Não aguento mais olhar pra cara do nosso sistema de override de strings :/ Mas tá certo

Comment: Corrigido para: "Respondeu depois de mais de 30 dias e foi a primeira resposta com 2 ou mais pontos"

Comment: Ótimo! Agora vou procurar mais bugs de tradução pra te passar :D @Gabe

Comment: @bfavaretto Em nome de Dijkstra, vade retro!